# FFMPeg Problem ( -bash: locate: command not found )

Tags: ffmpeg

Well, i tried the below mention way to check whether the FFMpeg extension exists or not for the Server:

```
if(extension_loaded('ffmpeg'))

    echo 'FFMPeg Exists on server';

else

    echo 'No FFMPeg';
```

While FFMpeg is working file in my local computer, but still it shows the result "No FFMPeg" in my local system.

Can anybody have some solution for it?

Answer (score 2):

From the error message in the title I guess that the programme "locate" is not installed on your computer and therefore the check that tries to locate ffmpeg always fails.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand. If you're running "ffmpeg" on your Shell (via ssh or something) it works, but your PHP code (I guess it's PHP) reports it's not there?

Make sure you have the ffmpeg extension enabled in your php.ini.

Alternatively: Do phpinfo(); in PHP and check the output for ffmpeg. It it's not there, you most certainly need to enable the extension.
If ffmpeg is displayed in the output of phpinfo() it looks like extension_loaded() has a bug. In this case you could try checking the returned array of get_loaded_extensions().